# How to get image as image file object from image url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, image, reactjs

```
for(let k = 0; k < propertyDetailResponse.images.length; k++) {
   let ImgFile = new File(["image"], propertyDetailResponse.images[k].image);
   this.state.gallery.image_ids.push(ImgFile)
}
```

Here is my code. `propertyDetailResponse.images[k].image` contains the image URL. I need `ImgFile` as a image file object as we get while uploading a image file

Comment: This seems like a very X/Y question. For what reason do you need to do this? There's almost certainly a better solution

Comment: I need get a image file object from an image url

Comment: I got that, but I'm asking *why*. It's a very odd thing to need to do, and is not at all simple.